# Spring Data JPA Hibernate query cache is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot starter data jpa 2.6.4

Hibernate Second level query cache doesn't work, every time the sql query gets called.

Not able to understand what actually got missed.

If anyone has faced a similar issue, please post your answers

application.properties:

```
#HIBERNATE SECOND LEVEL CACHE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Entity.class:

```
package com.dhre.realconnect.notificationService.notificationEntities;

import com.dhre.realconnect.common.dto.BaseObject;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

/**
 * Entity class for event to lookup up from list of all type of event and map to
 * eventID
 * 
 * @author M1081522
 *
 */
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Events")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Events extends BaseObject {

   @Serial
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @Column
   private int eventID;
   @Column
   private String eventCode;
   @Column
   private int categoryID;
   @Column
   private int eventCategoryID;
   @Column
   private boolean isMandatory;
   @Column
   private String eventDescription;
   @Column
   private Timestamp lastUpdated;
   @Column
   private boolean includeAttachments;
   @Column
   private boolean isCustomerEvent;
   @Column
   private boolean useDefaultSender;
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.dhre.realconnect.notificationService.notificationRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.dhre.realconnect.notificationService.notificationEntities.Events;

import javax.persistence.QueryHint;

/**
 * Repository for Event table in Notification database
 * @author M1081522
 *
 */
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Events, Integer>{

   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE EventCode=:eventCode", nativeQuery = true)
   @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.CACHEABLE, value = "true"))
   Optional<Events> getByEventCode(String eventCode);

}
```

Configuration:

```
package com.dhre.realconnect.notificationService.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.dhre.realconnect.notificationService.notificationEntities.MessageEntity;
/**
 * Notification Database config class
 * 
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "notificationEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "notificationTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "com.dhre.realconnect.notificationService.notificationRepository" })
public class NotificationDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.notification.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.notification.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.notification.username}")
    private String databaseUserName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.notification.password}")
    private String databasePassword;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.show-sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    // TODO add multiple data source needs to be added

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="notificationEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean notificationEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { MessageEntity.class.getPackageName() });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();

        // make rest calls here to fetch username and password from the configration
        // server

        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSourceBuilder.url(databaseUrl);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(databaseUserName);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(databasePassword);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="notificationTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager notificationTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(notificationEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.properties.dialect", hibernateDialect);

        return properties;
    }

}
```

I have tried the hibernate second level query caching, but it is not working

Comment: I would remove the `@Query` (leave the `@QueryHint`) and rename the method to `findByEventCode` that will use a JPQL query instead of a SQL query. Additionally the `@Repository` on the interface doesn't do anything so you want to remove that. Finally using `@Data` with `@Entity` is a no-go, it generates the wrong `equals`/`hashCode` which with caching is of importance. See https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ how to implement those proper.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I have tried all of them but still it is not working. I have noticed that even the findById i.e., hibernate second level cache is also not working. Any clue what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Are you manually constructing the `EntityManagerFactory`? Show some working code that we can use to reproduce. What you show here should work, so there must be something in your setup that disables it (or ignores the properties).

Comment: Hi Deinum, your assumption is correct and I have added the configuration file which has the overridden changes for the entity manager factory. Please have a look and if possible please suggest your ideas on it.

Comment: What is the reason for this configuration? You are using Spring Boot and I don't see anything in there that warrants that configuration, unless you have multiple entitymanagerfactories (if not remove this configuration). When doing manual configuration you disable auto confiugration and thus the properties in the `application.properties` don't apply. You will need to add them to the `additionalProperties` you are creating in code. But as stated if you only have 1 `EntityManagerFactory` remove this configuration completely.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I am actually having multiple entity manager factories and I have tried the additional properties suggestion it worked great. Now I'm able to cache the queries, Thanks to you :)

Comment: Even if you have multiple and want to share some configuration you might want to consider using the `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`. That way you can have global `spring.jpa` properties which apply to all instances and modify only that what differs. That probably will make your configuration a bit easier.